# Why Empty 'docker-machine ls' output when running without sudo, while 'sudo docker-machine ls' works?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sudo, docker-machine

I have added my user to the docker group, and docker and docker-compose commands are working fine but `docker ps` also shows empty list and works with sudo.My docker-machine commands have problems, this is leading to me not being able to `eval $(docker-machine env mymachine)` and `eval $(sudo docker-machine env coding-platform-dev)` doesn't work either.

When I compose a yml file it goes to 0.0.0.0 instead of the assigned ip to docker-machine in my case `192.168.99.100`

Comment: I have the same problem, though weirdly I don't remember having this problem until recently (but I could be misremembering; it's been a while).  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't. Not a lot of users use docker-machine like the docker service.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out why this happens.  When machines are created with `docker-machine`, all info about created machines including their config files, SSH keys, etc. are stored under `${HOME}/.docker/machine` for the user that created them.

So if a machine was created as root, those machines can only be seen by root.  `docker-machine` doesn't work like `docker` itself insofar as there is no daemon responsible for managing machines--just a bunch of static config files represent the available machines.  So even if you're part of the `docker` group on your system this is irrelevant to how `docker-machine` functions.

Comment: Yes I realized this and created a `docker-machine` using the non root user, and it didn't help. Maybe it has something to do with the daemon?

Comment: No, I don't think it has anything to do with the daemon, since docker-machine really has no interaction with your local docker daemon (it doesn't even need or use a local docker daemon to run, which is part of the point of it).  That's weird though.  When you create a machine try to see where it's creating the `.docker/machine/<machine-name>` directory.